# Why is, x ~ y if x $\geq$ y not symmetric?

Tags: relations

> I am confused to why the relation, x ~ y if x $\geq$ y is not symmetric?

Because if x ~ x then x $\geq$ x would still hold true. What am I not getting?

Comment: $x \sim x$ is the **reflexivity** requirement.  Symmetry is something else.

Comment: Symmetric means that $x \sim y$ implies $y \sim x$. Does $x \geq y$ imply $y \geq x$?

Comment: By definition, this relation would be symmetric if $x\leqslant y$ implied $y\leqslant x$, but this not true.

Comment: @kccu no it does not thanks for helping!